# How to set color of existing css class, from props of a react component

Tags: css, reactjs, video.js

I am trying to modify the styling (colors) of existing class from the videojs Library.

I found that we can modify from css file. But I need to modify from the colour we get from react props, which is dynamic each time.

So, we have a class called `vjs-control-bar` coming from the videojs library to which we need to apply a `color` property with the value coming from react-props for eg. `this.props.color`. How we can achieve this ?

```
<div data-vjs-player>
  <video ref={node => (this.videoNode = node)} className="video-js" />
</div>
```

The `vjs-control-bar` class wasn't here as it is coming from the `video-js` library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *right* approach here would be to use one of those CSSinJS libraries and add rules that target the DOM elements that are rendered by the VideoJS library you are using.

Another alternative is to simply render a `<style></style>` tag in the component where you render the `<video>` component using the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop.

Here is an example of how this might work:

```js
function InnerComponent() {
  return <h1 class="title">Text Color</h1>;
}

function App(props) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <style
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `
        .title {
          color: ${props.color};
        }
      `
        }}
      />
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <InnerComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/embed/white-star-9o897